# Oracle - Unique values combinations from multiple columns, but returning other columns

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to figure out how to pull different data scenarios from my table for testing.  Assume my table has these three fields `FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3`.  If I want to find the various scenarios in my data I could simply do this

```
select distinct FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3 from <table>
```

And this works.  The problem is I have a plethora of other fields I need data from as well, but it doesn't matter what that data is as long as it's associated with the resulting record.  So for example if the above query returned this as one of the results

```
FIELD1  FIELD2  FIELD3
----------------------
Y       Blue    31
```

I would want to see the other content fields (4 through 10 lets say).  Now wether those came from record number #30 or record #20000 (assuming those records contained those 3 returned values) it doesn't matter as long as all the fields were returned by said record.

Hope that makes sense and someone can help!

Comment: Do the values in FIELD4 through FIELD10 all have to come from the same record? Or can FIELD4 come from record #30 and FIELD5 come from record #20000, etc?

Comment: @Shannon - I guess I don't, but it would be preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
SELECT field1, 
       field2,
       field3,
       field4,
       ....
       field10
  FROM( SELECT field1,
               field2,
               ...,
               field10,
               rowid rid,
               min(rowid) OVER (partition by field1, field2, field3) min_rid
          FROM your_table_name )
 WHERE rid = min_rid
```

should work.  If there is a primary key, you could use that rather than the `ROWID`, I'm just using that to have something that is guaranteed to be unique.

For your curveball

```
SELECT field1, 
       field2,
       field3,
       field4,
       ....
       field10
  FROM( SELECT field1,
               field2,
               (CASE WHEN field3 IS NULL
                     THEN 'NULL'
                     ELSE field3
                 END) field3,
               ...,
               field10,
               rowid rid,
               min(rowid) OVER (partition by field1, 
                                             field2, 
                                             (CASE WHEN field3 IS NULL
                                                   THEN 'NULL'
                                                   ELSE field3
                                               END) min_rid
          FROM your_table_name )
 WHERE rid = min_rid
```

Comment: Awesome - it's taking a while to crunch, but I'm taking that as a good sign.  1 curve ball though.  Say field3 can be null or have some value.  When the value is not null I want to treat those identically.  Something to the effect of this 

case when field3 is null then null
 else 'X'
end as field3,

Just not sure how I would implement that in both the outer select and the partition.

Comment: @dscl - Covered the curveball

Comment: Thanks Justin, I tried it on my own and almost had it covered was just having a '( )' issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select a.* 
from tblA a, 
     (select min(rowid), col_1, col_2 from tblA
      group by col_1, col_2) b
where a.rowid=b.rid;
```